# how to start/run a windows service at particular time (say: 12:00 PM) every day?

Tags: windows-services, app-config, scheduled-tasks

**Background:** I have developed a windows service which runs once every day and does the work (every thing is just right!)

**Issue:** the service runs exactly at the same time (last run time) the other day..
       Ex: If I start the service at 4:00 PM today so it will run again at 4:00 PM every day.

**My solution** till yet (but not working fine) I want it to configure it self with the **StartTime** and **IntervalTime** mentioned in the app.config file and run at that time everyday (regardless of when I have started it)

Having problems with this silly thing .. Please help in this regards with sample code.
Your help is really appreciated, Thanks in advance.

For further clarification, if I have mentioned in app.config

```
key="StartTime" value="12:00"
key="Interval" value="86400000"
```

so it must run on 12:00 PM every day (as interval period is 86400000 milliseconds i.e. 1day) regardless of the time when I started it or make it live.

Comment: Wouldn't using a scheduled task make more sense here?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't want to create a service, but a scheduled task.

Comment: No I want to create a windows service - that suites best in my requirements and all is working fine, also service is runs everyday - just want it to run at particular time which i have mentioned in app.config or some other solution if you have.

Comment: where are you guys - please help, I need this thing working urgently!

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a scheduled task that starts the service at a specific time and stops it at another via a **batch file**.  You would utilize the commands `net stop myservice` and `net start myservice` in the batch file.